# ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable in K-Means Clustering Mahout

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout, k-means

I am using Mahout commands for K-Mean Clustering, the input file is 
"KMeansData.csv" and the data is in this format,

```
John,M,30,Pepsi,US
Jack,M,25,Coke,US
David,M,34,Pepsi,UK
Ted,M,37,Limca,CAN
Robert,M,23,Limca,US
Adrian,M,31,Pepsi,US
Craig,M,37,Coke,UK
Katie,F,23,Limca,UK
Nancy,F,32,Pepsi,UK
```

i am able to complete the below steps successfully,they are,

```
./mahout seqdirectory -i /root/Mahout/Clustering/ -o /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-seqdir -c UTF-8 -chunk 1 

./mahout seq2sparse -i /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-seqdir -o /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-seqdir-sparse-kmeans --maxDFPercent 85 --namedVector

./mahout kmeans -i /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-seqdir-sparse-kmeans/tfidf-vectors/ -c /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans-clusters -o /root/Mahout/reuters21578/root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure -x 10 -k 5 -ow --clustering -cl
```

but when i use clustedump :

```
./mahout clusterdump -i  /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans-clusters -d  /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-seqdir-sparse-kmeans/dictionary.file-0 -dt sequencefile -b 100 -n 20 --evaluate -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure --pointsDir  /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans-clusters -o  /root/Mahout/temp/cluster-output.txt
```

it gives me below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
at org.apache.mahout.utils.clustering.ClusterDumper.readPoints(ClusterDumper.java:298)
at org.apache.mahout.utils.clustering.ClusterDumper.init(ClusterDumper.java:245)
at org.apache.mahout.utils.clustering.ClusterDumper.run(ClusterDumper.java:152)
at org.apache.mahout.utils.clustering.ClusterDumper.main(ClusterDumper.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
```

can anybody idea on how to remove this error,using commands as i dont have any java program here which i can tailor.

Answer (score 1):

the input to clusterdump should be

```
 ./mahout clusterdump -i /root/Mahout/temp/parsedtext-kmeans/clusteredPoints
```

which is a sequencefile of

and not as you had it.